# How to run unit tests on Cassandra binary distribution

Tags: maven, cassandra, ant, cassandra-3.0, build.xml

I'm trying to check whether the cassandra binary distribution [(link)](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/cassandra/3.11.2/apache-cassandra-3.11.2-bin.tar.gz) is working on IBM s390x platform or not. I can start the server and perform db queries on it. Now I want to run its unit tests, but this distribution(tar) doesn't have the test source. So I want to use the test source from its [Github](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/tree/cassandra-3.11.2). How can I achieve this. What files to replace and what changes to make in `build.xml`.

Note: I'm able to build and run tests on the github source separately(using ant).

Comment: Why don't you try the [cassandra stress tool](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsCStress.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Can run unit tests with `ant test` see [here](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/development/testing.html#unit-testing). if your using an IBM specific JDK I would not expect it to work out of the gate with a normal distribution but with OpenJDK it may.

Theres likely multiple steps to get it working under a new platform, as Cassandra is mostly run with, and tested against OpenJDK and Oracle JDK. It explicitly requires java8 for oracle or openjdk as a [prerequisite](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/installing.html#prerequisites).

You might wanna look through [the official development guide](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/development/index.html) which gives instructions on setting up development environment and running the tests.